# Mapping Incoming request using regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a task which is to create an xml file with basically these elements:-

incoming request = sites/suppliers(.*?)  should redirect to http://home.company/sites/sup$1

I'll read this xml file in Global.asax Application_BeginRequest event.
Get the incoming request and check the xml file and do any redirection if necessary.

Could you guys please help me by giving the code in CSharp on how to acheive this.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make XML Like this

```
<SiteRoot><Site URL="" KeyWord=""><SiteRoot>
```

Load this xml as `XMLDocument` object in Begin_Request, in method check the url or key words in the request, use `Xmldoc.SelectSingleNode` to select single url. Use `Server.Transfer` to redirect to the URL found using `SelectSingleNode` method

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I think I need to use regular expression to check the incoming url to see that wether it match to any of the specified pattern in the XML lists. My XML file would contains sime thing like this <url><oldUrl>http://www.somesite.com/sites/suppliers(.*?)</oldUrl><newUrl>http://www.newsite.com/sites/supplier$1</newUrl><url>

Comment: you can use contains or regular expression in xpath to find the url to redirect to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405060/can-i-use-a-regex-in-an-xpath-expression