# How Can I search for xml tag names in java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I need to search a specific xml node. I know part of its name but not the entire name... How can I get that element with part of the name?

I know it can be resolved using xpath, but I dont know how. For example...:

```
<root>
<head/>
<body> <SuperAsdf> hi </SuperAsdf>
</body>
<root/>
```

I know that have to be a tag with "Super" but I dont know that it could have "Asdf", so I need a xPath expression to find all the tags with "Super".

Also, what function supports xpaths in java?

I'm using getElementsByTagName, but I read that it cant interpretate xpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions would be overkill for this purpose. Just use an XPath expression like:

```
"//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Super')]"
```

---

Regarding Java functions for XPath... see [the code here](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xpath_apis.html) for example, or look at the class  [XPathFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathFactory.html).

Answer (score 0):

XPath 1.0 doesn't support regular expressions but you can still do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405060/can-i-use-a-regex-in-an-xpath-expression) to achieve what you're trying to do (Using only XPath functions).

Xpath 2.0 support regular expressions with functions like `matches()` and `replace()` (more information [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xpath.html)).

A regular expression in your case would look like:

```
(Super).*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XPath expression that LarsH suggested with the [XPathAPI library](http://svario.it/xpathapi) ([javadoc](http://svario.it/xpathapi/doc)):

```
List<Node> nodes =
    XPathAPI.selectListOfNodes(doc, "//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Super')]")
```

If you have an XPath-2.0-compliant processor (for example Saxon) on your class path, JAXP and XPathAPI will pick it up and use it to select nodes.

(Disclaimer, I'm the author of the XPathAPI library.)