# Select element with a changing Id string using XPath

Tags: xpath

I have a textarea control with an Id that goes something like this:

```
<textarea id="NewTextArea~~51887~~1" rows="2"/>
```

And the xpath that has worked before has been

```
//textarea[@id, "NewTextArea~~51887~~1"]
```

But now the '51887' portion of the id is become diverse (changing every time) so I need to select the NewtextArea~~*****~~1 element without actually specifying the number. Is there a way I can wildcard part of the string so that it will match a particular pattern? I tried using starts-with and ends-with but couldn't get it to work:

```
//textarea[starts-with(@id, 'NewTextArea~~') and ends-with(@name, '~~1')]
```

Bare in mind there are other fields with the difference being the number on the end.

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried using starts-with and ends-with but couldn't get it to work:
>
> ```
> //textarea[starts-with(@id, 'NewTextArea~~') and ends-with(@name, '~~1')]
> ```

**[`ends-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-ends-with) is available as a standard function only in XPath 2.0 and you seem to be using XPath 1.0**.

**Use**:

```
//textarea
   [starts-with(@id, 'NewTextArea~~')
  and
   substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 2) = '~~1'
   ]
```

**Explanation**:

See the answer to this question, for how to implement `ends-with()` in XPath 1.0:

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/405507/36305**