# Can i use regular expression in an Xpath expression

Tags: xpath

I am trying to find an element by Xpath,  Something like:

```
.//*[@id='images__row__94c744c1-dc7e-4c04-a78a-0f34d175f10f']/td[7]/div/a[1]
```

How can I capture the tags with regex like:

```
images__row__([A-Z0-9]{8}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{12}).
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405060/can-i-use-a-regex-in-an-xpath-expression

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Check out the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) - you may want to improve the formatting of your question so that it is a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

For RegEx support you need XPath 2.0 you expression would look like this:

//*[matches(@id, '^images_row_[a-z0-9]{8}-([a-z0-9]{4}-){3}[a-z0-9]{12}$')]/........