# Regex inside Nokogiri for numbers?

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri

I have this code, and I need to add a regex ahead of "href=" for integers:

```
f = File.open("us.html")
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(f)

ans = doc.css('a[href=]')

puts doc
```

I tried doing:

```
ans = doc.css('a[href=\d]
```

or:

```
ans = doc.css('a[href="\d"])
```

but it doesn't work. Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Comment: Are you sure `doc.css(...)` accepts regular expressions in CSS selectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a regular expression, I believe you will have to do that manually. It cannot be done with a CSS or XPath selector.

You can do it by iterating through the elements and comparing their `href` attribute to your regular expression. For example:

```
html = %q{
<html>
  <a href='1'></a>
  <a href='adf'></a>
</html>
}

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
ans = doc.css('a[href]').select{ |e| e['href'] =~ /\d/}
#=> <a href="1"></a>
```

Comment: @MarkThomas You can match numbers (per the OP's desire), but [you cannot match a regex in XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/a/405507/405017) which is what the answer says.

Comment: +1 for correctly suggesting that sometimes it's easier and faster (for the programmer; slower for the computer) to get halfway with CSS or XPath and then finish up the problem in Ruby.

Comment: @Phrogz Thanks for pointing that out. In my initial read, I interpreted the "it" in "It cannot be done..." to be "The OP's problem".

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in XPath:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = %q{
<html>
  <a href='1'></a>
  <a href='adf'></a>
</html>
}

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

puts doc.xpath('//a[@href[number(.) = .]]')
#=> <a href="1"></a>
```

The XPath function `number()` does a conversion to a number. If it equals the node itself, then the node *is* a number. It is even possible to check a range using inequality operators.

Comment: Is it possible to check if the attribute contains a number (using xpath)? For example, how would you make the link `<a href='h1'></a>` also be included in the results?

Comment: In `number(.)` - is `.` the `@href` attribue node ?