# Finding all links matching specific URL template in an HTML page

Tags: python, regex, xpath, html-parsing, lxml

So lets say I have the following base url `http://example.com/Stuff/preview/v/{id}/fl/1/t/`. There are a number of urls with different {id}s on the page being parsed. I want to find all the links matching this template in an HTML page.

I can use xpath to just match to a part of the template`//a[contains(@href,preview/v]`  or just use regexes, but I was wondering if anyone knew a more elegant way to match to the entire template using xpath and regexes so its fast and the matches are definitely correct.

Thanks.

Edit. I timed it on a sample page. With my internet connection and 100 trials the iteration takes 0.467 seconds on average and BeautifulSoup takes 0.669 seconds.

Also if you have Scrapy its one can use [Selectors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html).

```
  data=get(url).text
  sel = Selector(text=data, type="html")
  a=sel.xpath('//a[re:test(@href,"/Stuff/preview/v/\d+/fl/1/t/")]//@href').extract()
```

Average time on this is also 0.467

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use regexes in the `xpath` expressions using `lxml`, since [`lxml` supports `xpath 1.0`](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) and `xpath 1.0` [doesn't support regular expression search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405060/can-i-use-a-regex-in-an-xpath-expression).

Instead, you can find all the links on a page using [`iterlinks()`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#working-with-links), iterate over them and check the `href` attribute value:

```
import re
import lxml.html

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(data)

pattern = re.compile("http://example.com/Stuff/preview/v/\d+/fl/1/t/")
for element, attribute, link, pos in tree.iterlinks():
    if not pattern.match(link):
        continue
    print link
```

---

An alternative option would be to use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) html parser:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = "your html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

pattern = re.compile("http://example.com/Stuff/preview/v/\d+/fl/1/t/")
print soup.find_all('a', {'href': pattern})
```

To make `BeautifulSoup` parsing faster you can [let it use `lxml`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
```

Also, you can make use of a [`SoupStrainer`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#soupstrainer) class that lets you parse only specific web page parts instead of a whole page.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This works , but I was more inclined on using xpath, because BeautifulSoup is fairly very slow and I am doing this matching a very large number of times. Iterating might be faster, but well haven't tested that.

Comment: @Artii please see the update. I'm still working on the answer though.

Comment: I timed it on a sample page. With my internet connection and  100 trials the iteration takes 0.467 seconds on average and BeautifulSoup takes 0.669 seconds.

Comment: @zx81 thanks, I see you like regular expressions and non-regex solutions :)

Comment: I absolutely love regex, and I almost never give non-regex solutions to regex questions... And I know that it's often not the best tool... So I enjoy it when someone shows other ways! :)