# Xpath Attribute REGEX

Tags: python, regex, xpath

Here is my code so far:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://web.international.ucla.edu/institute/events')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

event_title = tree.xpath('//a[@href="/institute/event/<<<REGEX>>>"]/text()')

print "Event Title: ", event_title
```

I'm scraping the page http://web.international.ucla.edu/institute/events for event data, and I'd like to capture the titles. They are identified by 5-digit numbers. How can I do this?

Comment: Try this `event_title = tree.xpath('//a[@href="/institute/event/[0-9]{5}"]/text()')`

Comment: I did, I think. I got an empty array. Let me try again.

Comment: Yup, I got `Event Title:  []` as a result.

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to use regexes in the xpath?

Comment: No, regexes are not part of XPath expressions.

Comment: Why not just use `event_title = tree.xpath('//a[@href="/institute/event"]/text()')` and then process it as needed?

Comment: Is there a better way to get event data other than this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [cannot use regular expressions in XPath 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405060/can-i-use-a-regex-in-an-xpath-expression) (even if regexes would surely be useful there!). In XPath 2.0 (which lxml does not support), regexes can be used in some functions, for instance `matches()` or `replace()`.

If I understood correctly, you are looking for this piece of data:

```
<a href='/institute/event/11147'>Papel Picado Workshop Series: Session 5</a>
```

You can find those `a` elements with

```
//a[starts-with(@href,'/institute/event/')]
```

But note that this returns a *list* of elements - whereas it seems that you expect one single item as the result. Please explain more clearly what exactly you need as the result.

As a suggestion, how about this:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://web.international.ucla.edu/institute/events')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

event_titles = tree.xpath('//a[starts-with(@href,"/institute/event/")]/text()')

for event_title in event_titles:
    print "Event Title: ", event_title
```

And the result will be

```
Event Title:  Papel Picado Workshop Series: Session 5
Event Title:  Cacahuatl: The Origins and Global Impact of Chocolate
Event Title:  “Institutionalizing Numbers in Post-Colonial Africa”
Event Title:  The Daniel Pearl Memorial Lecture presents A Conversation with Leon Panetta, part of the Luskin Lecture Series
Event Title:  Persian Women and Other Lies: Story-telling as Historical Retrieval
Event Title:  UCLA EVENT: Making Micronesia
Event Title:  Teach-In: Out of Nowhere? Some Questions, Answers, and Discussion about ISIS
Event Title:  Impossible Testimonies:  Literature and Aesthetics in the Aftermath of the Armenian Genocide
Event Title:  “Casa Grande” Film Screening
Event Title:  The Headscarf Debates: Conflicts of National Belonging
Event Title:  Rethinking History in Chinese Central Asia
Event Title:  Screening: "REBEL: Loreta Velazquez, Civil War Soldier and Spy"
Event Title:  "How Terrorism is Designed to Work"
Event Title:  Matthäus Rest Talk - Dreaming of Pipes: The politics of in/visibility around Nepal’s spectral infrastructures
Event Title:  The Barber of Damascus: Nouveau Literacy in the Eighteenth-Century Levant
Event Title:  Representation of "Apology": a Comparative Study on Narratives by Korean and Japanese Media
Event Title:  "They Can Live in the Desert but Nowhere Else": A History of the Armenian Genocide
Event Title:  Colloquium: Towards a contents-platform conglomerate?
Event Title:  Picturing Political Abstractions in Song/Jin Painting
Event Title:  ISIS and the Enslavement and Trafficking of Women: An Evening with Dr. Khaled Abou El Fadi
Event Title:  Korean Culture Night
Event Title:  Genocide and Global History: A Conference on the 100th Anniversary of the Armenian Genocide
Event Title:  U.S.-China: Economic Ties, Growth Strategies and Investment Opportunities
Event Title:  Human Rights and the Armenian Genocide
Event Title:  Gerschenkron Redux? New Evidence on Shanghai's Pre-War Stock Exchange and Its Implications for the Chinese Economy at Present
```