# Finding WebElement by Xpath Using Regex

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following WebElements:

```
<input id="" type="checkbox" value="/p1/foobar1" name="checkbox1" partition="p1" onclick=""/>
<input id="" type="checkbox" value="/p1/foobar" name="checkbox2" partition="p1" onclick=""/>
<input id="" type="checkbox" value="/p2/foobar2" name="checkbox3" partition="p2" onclick=""/>
```

And I'm wanting to find the 2nd element in the above source (the one with with a value of `/p1/foobar`) based on value attribute using regex in an xpath.  I have tried the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[matches(@value,'.*\\/foobar$')]"));
```

But it throws an InvalidSelectorException.  I've gotten it to work with cssSelector like so ...

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(input[value$='\\/foobar']));
```

But I'm still curious how to accomplish this with xpath.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**  I should also note that I want to be able to find this element without knowing the characters before the last slash (aka `/p1/`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
//input[@value='/p1/foobar']
```

If you don't know what it starts with, you have to resort to functions:

```
//input[contains(@value, 'foobar') and substring-after(@value, 'foobar') = '']
```

Here is a 'fiddle'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
<input id="" name="checkbox1" onclick="" partition="p1" type="checkbox" value="/p1/foobar1"/>
<input id="" name="checkbox2" onclick="" partition="p1" type="checkbox" value="/p1/foobar"/>
<input id="" name="checkbox3" onclick="" partition="p2" type="checkbox" value="/p2/foobar2"/>
</result>
```

http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/4dc56e27ca1674ea0b5b48357214b907

As noted in [Can I use a Regex in an XPath expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405060/can-i-use-a-regex-in-an-xpath-expression), XPath 1.0 doesn't support regular expressions.

Here are many examples:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is a list of XPath functions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256180(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response but please see my edit.  I'm trying to accomplish finding this element without knowledge of the characters before the last slash.

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath contains function. Fairly complicated. Probably you do not want to go this route. But this can be done also

```
//input[contains(@value,'foo') and (not(contains(@value,'foobar1'))) and (not(contains(@value,'foobar2')))]
```

***Keep the complexity in mind, I think the CssSelector is the best fit for this scenario.**

Comment: That won't work because the other element attributes also contain `foobar`.

Comment: Chloe is correct.  This will find the first webelement since it also contains `foobar`, not the second.

Comment: @Saifur I'm really trying to use `matches` and regex to accomplish this webelement find.  It should not depend on knowledge of all the other source.

Comment: @user2150250 I am afraid as per my knowledge Selenium only supports xpath version 1 which does not support extensive regex search

Answer (score 0):

XPath does not support regex. You will have to resort to other XPath functions, for your example you can use something like:

```
//input[ends-with(@value,'foobar')]
```

There is a nice list of XPath functions [here](http://zvon.org/comp/r/ref-XPath_2.html).

Comment: `ends-with` is a part of xpath version 2.0. Does Selenium support that?

Comment: yeah doesn't seem to be working for me unfortunately.