# xpath - find datetimes textnodes

Tags: xpath

I have some XML with elements that contain values with mixed data types. For example:

```
<someroot>
    <event>
        <dt>21.10.15 08:00</dt>
    </event>
    <event>
        <dt>10:00</dt>
    </event>
    <event>
        <dt>21/10/15 08:00</dt>
    </event>
</someroot>
```

How can I find all the text nodes that contain only datetime values?  Note that `dt` elements can be at different depths and may just contain times.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I noticed you concerns about the quality of your English and so have tried to help out by fixing up your terminology and generally tidied up the grammar.

Comment: This might put you on the right track ~ [Can I use a Regex in an XPath expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405060/can-i-use-a-regex-in-an-xpath-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xpath doesn't provide ways to find text nodes by mask/regex
But it has usefull functions like starts-with(),ends-with()