# Regular expression for selenium webdriver xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver

xpath = ".//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_dgDataList_ctl06_btnEdit']";

here 106  is varying every time ,  how to use regular expression in xpath

Answer (score 0):

```
xpath = ".//*[matches  (@id, 'ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_dgDataList_ct\d+_btnEdit']";
```

Comment: Thanks, but  "\d" shows as invalid expression and displasy error on the line.  is it something i am missing ?

Comment: XPATH 2.0 has support for regular expressions, I believe. If its 1.0, then you need to check this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405060/can-i-use-a-regex-in-an-xpath-expression