# Use Regex with selenium driver tag selectors

Tags: java, selenium, css-selectors, tags

I'm trying to configure a regex to find all elements with such attributes.
The HTML tag is something like:

```
<img class="my-img-12">
```

where the latest 2 numbers are always different.
I tried these ways but no one seems to work:

```
    List<WebElement> allElement = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("img[class^='my-img-\\d{1,}']"));
```

or

```
    List<WebElement> allElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//img[starts-with(@class, 'my-img-') and  'my-img-' = translate(@class, '0123456789', '') and string-length(@class) > 1])"));
```

the latest option was suggested here: [Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405060/can-i-use-a-regex-in-an-xpath-expression)

if you're thinking about this:

```
    List<WebElement> allElement = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("img[class^='my-img-']"));
```

It's not gonna works because there could be some attributes like this:

```
<img class="my-img-wordsOccurrences">
```

Comment: Maybe something like this img[matches(class,"^(my-img-)\d{1,}")] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using XPath contains:

```
List<WebElement> allElement = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath(".//<define root element here>[contains(@class, 'my-img-')]")
```