# XPath wildcards for name attribute in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: xpath

I want to use a Wildcards in for the name attribute. For example, this is my regular XPath:

```
name = "view:_id1:_id4:cbMain:cbChairman"
```

I want to replace the _id1:_id4:cbMain: reference with a wildcard because the number is dynamic. I'm looking for something like this:

```
name = "view:*:cbChairman"
```

I don't know how to solve this issue. Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: Your XPath doesn't really look like XPath.. Did you mean predicate `[@name="view:_id1:_id4:cbMain:cbChairman"]`?  Show your XML sample

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a Regex in an XPath expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405060/can-i-use-a-regex-in-an-xpath-expression)